# PrimeFaces fileupload ie9 not multiple select

Tags: jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces 4.0 FileUpload multiple="true" but i am not selection multiple. only one file select.
it is work in chrome but is not work ie9. Why?

xhtml

```
<p:dialog id="DosyaDlg" widgetVar="DosyaDialog" modal="true" resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" header="#{msg['header.dialog.dosyaEkle']}" closeOnEscape="true">
            <h:form id="DosyaForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{yazilimArizaBean.dosyaYenile}" dragDropSupport="false" fileLimit="3" sizeLimit="1000000" mode="advanced" multiple="true" uploadLabel="#{msg['button.yukle']}"
                    cancelLabel="#{msg['button.iptal']}"  description="Select Images" label="#{msg['button.sec']}" allowTypes="/(\\.|\\/)(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|txt|png)$/" oncomplete="DosyaDialog.hide()" />
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Thank you for your helps

Comment: Just my experience, IE != Other. I never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like IE9 does not support multiple File Upload from Primefaces post v2.2.1 (meaning your v4.0 is included in the non-working ones).

See issue here : https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3869

This will not get fixed.

Comment: think internet explorer bugs,is it?